# When we change our name, our name on community wiki posts doesn't change

Tags: bug

I was going through one of my old post and figured out it still showing my old display name even though rest of posts by me are showing correct names,

[Books Recommended for Beginner SharePoint architect](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31845/books-recommended-for-beginner-sharepoint-architect)

Possibly a bug. ("TimeToShine" was my old display name.)

Comment: Looks like it has changed now, doesn't it? Maybe a timer job issue, and we know what they are like when failing :-)